# stabilizer of the pair in regular 8 gon

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The group $D_8$ acts on the regular 8-gon with vertices numbered sequentially 1,...,8. What is the order of the stabilizer of the pair of opposite vertices {1,5}?

My thought is that I need to find actions in $D_8$ such that when I take the action on 8-gon, the vertices 1, 5 should stay in the same position.

Then arent'  e (identity)  and u (flip over a line that passes vertices 1 and 5) the only actions? Am I misunderstanding "pair of opposite vertices {1,5}"?

Comment: What about 180 degree rotation?

Comment: doesn't that make 1 go to 5, and 5 go to 1?  Is that ok as long as I keep a pair in the same position even 1 and 5 are swapped?

Comment: $\{1,5\} = \{5,1\}$. This is a set - it has no ordering.

Comment: oh~ so 1 and 5 can be swapped.  So it's also true when 1 is at the place of 5 and at the same time, 5 is at the place of 1.Thank you!